# How do I send array of urls to another view and convert to images?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, networking

First I need to Parse JSON to get URLs. The with those urls I convert them to images to load a UICollectionView. I need to send over an array of URLs to do the same for the other view. The catch is I need to set the initial image as the thumbnail I just clicked and then loop though an array to display the following images. Here is my code and please help!

```
 class HomepageCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var imageCache = NSCache()

    var hingeImagesArray = [HingeImage]()
    var arrayToHoldConvertedUrlToUIImages = [UIImage]()
    var task: NSURLSessionDataTask?

   //full of urls
   var hingeImageUrls = [String]()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Makes the network call for HingeImages
        refreshItems()


    }





    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hingeImagesArray.count


    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageReuseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

        let image = hingeImagesArray[indexPath.row]


        if let imageURL = image.imageUrl {

            if let url = NSURL(string: imageURL) {



                //Check for cached images and if found set them to cells - works if images go off screen
                if let myImage = imageCache.objectForKey(image.imageUrl!) as? UIImage {

                    cell.collectionViewImage.image = myImage

                }else {



                // Request images asynchronously so the collection view does not slow down/lag
                self.task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

//                    if (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse == 400) {
//                        print("400")
//                    }



                        // Check if there is data returned
                        guard let data = data else {
                            return
                        }

                        // Create an image object from our data and assign it to cell


                        if let hingeImage = UIImage(data: data){



                          //Cache images/set key for it
                          self.imageCache.setObject(hingeImage, forKey: image.imageUrl!)



                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in




                                cell.collectionViewImage.image = hingeImage




                             })
                        }

                })

                task?.resume()

               }
            }

        }

        return cell
    }
















    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

            performSegueWithIdentifier("nextView", sender: cell)

        }else{
            print("no good")
        }
    }







    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        //Load imageView with the image clicked on
        //Must send over whole array with images to display in next screen



        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! ImageCollectionViewCell) {

            if segue.identifier == "nextView" {

                let galleryViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! GalleryViewController


               //We are passing the url to the next screen then making another request to show them
               let imageUrl = hingeImagesArray[indexPath.row]


                //passesd a single image 
                galleryViewController.imageUrlFromOtherScreen = imageUrl.imageUrl


                //Pasing array of urls 
                galleryViewController.arrayOfImageUrlsFromOtherView = hingeImageUrls






               //let image = arrayToHoldConvertedUrlToUIImages[indexPath.row]

                //galleryViewController.selectedImageFromPreviousScreen = image

               // galleryViewController.arrayOfImageObjects = arrayToHoldConvertedUrlToUIImages

                //print(arrayToHoldConvertedUrlToUIImages)


            }


        }

    }





    //Execute JSON request
    func refreshItems() {

        HingeClient.executeJSONNetworkRequest { (hingeImages, error) in

            guard let images = hingeImages else {
                print("Error getting images with JSON")
                return
            }


            //Loop through array and append URLs to new array
            for moreImages in hingeImages! {

                self.hingeImageUrls.append(moreImages.imageUrl!)

            }



            self.hingeImagesArray = images



            self.collectionView?.reloadData()


        }
    }
















}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done that I can see now is create a cache object to cache downloaded image accordingly with its URL. If you want to pass over your URLs array to another view, one possibility is to share your cache as global instance (e.g. a singleton object). So that from another view, you just check the cache whether or not the image is existed, then get it from cache or otherwise, need to request from server.